# tomcat8 ignores shared.loader property

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, servlets, java-native-interface

I am trying to write a simple servlet which just calls a native function.

First I tried to load the shared object in the servlet but then i got an "UnsatisfiedLinkError" because the library was already loaded in the JVM. After searching for this problem I found this [tomcat documentation](https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo#I.27m_encountering_classloader_problems_when_using_JNI_under_Tomcat).

It basically says that I must write a loader which gets executed when the server starts up. So I wrote the following class:

```
class MyLibLoader 
{
    static 
    {
        System.loadLibrary("foo");
    }

    native void doFoo();

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Lib loaded");
    }
}
```

compiled it into a .class file and put it in the "$CATALINA_HOME/shared/lib/" folder, edited the property "shared.loader" in the "catalina.properties" file to the following:

```
shared.loader="${catalina.home}/shared/lib"
```

after restarting the tomcat without errors i get the following Exception in the servlet:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Which means, by my understanding, that the JNI library is not loaded. I tried to change the library name to a name that definitely does not exist and there you go: I can restart the tomcat without errors that the library is not found. I also tried to put the loader in a .jar file an change the property to:

```
shared.loader="${catalina.home}/shared/lib/*.jar"
```

It didn't work too.

Based on this I assume that the tomcat just ignores the "shared.loader" property.